# Simplifying a MySQL Query with many left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has tags which reference another table in multiple languages. I wrote this query which does the job but isn't elegant and its very long winded:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.ID as CountryID,
    T1.Type AS CountryType,
    T2.Text AS CountryText,
    T3.Text AS CountryTitle,
    T4.Text AS Heading1,
    T5.Text AS Heading2,
    T6.Text AS Heading3,
    T7.Text AS Heading4,
    T8.Text AS Heading5,
    T9.Text AS Heading6,
    T10.Text AS Heading7,
    T11.Text AS Heading8,
    T12.Text AS Heading9,
    T13.Text AS Heading10,
    T14.Text AS Heading11,
    T15.Text AS Heading12,
    T16.Text AS Heading13,
    T17.Text AS Heading14,
    T18.Text AS Heading15,
    T19.Text AS Heading16,
    T20.Text AS Heading17,
    T21.Text AS Heading18,
    T22.Text AS Heading19,
    T23.Text AS Heading20
FROM 
    Countrys AS T1
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T2 ON T1.DESCRIPTION=T2.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T3 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_TITLE')=T3.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T4 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_1')=T4.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T5 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_2')=T5.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T6 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_3')=T6.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T7 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_4')=T7.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T8 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_5')=T8.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T9 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_6')=T9.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T10 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_7')=T10.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T11 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_8')=T11.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T12 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_9')=T12.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T13 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_10')=T13.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T14 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_11')=T14.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T15 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_12')=T15.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T16 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_13')=T16.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T17 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_14')=T17.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T18 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_15')=T18.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T19 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_16')=T19.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T20 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_17')=T20.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T21 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_18')=T21.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T22 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_19')=T22.TAG
    LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T23 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_20')=T23.TAG
WHERE
    T1.Type='Country_ENGLAND';
```

Is there a way I can simplify this query so that I don't have to have all those LEFT JOINS? Different countries will have different number of headings so I have to get all possible headings to ensure I get them all.

Something like this - I know this wont work, I'm just giving an example of what I am trying to do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
T1.ID as CountryID,
T1.Type AS CountryType,
T2.Text AS CountryText,
T3.Text AS CountryTitle,
T4.Text AS Headings?,

FROM 
Countrys AS T1
LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T2 ON T1.DESCRIPTION=T2.TAG
LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T3 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_TITLE')=T3.TAG
LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T4 ON CONCAT(T1.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_%')=T4.TAG AND T4.TAG IS NOT NULL,
WHERE
T1.Type='Country_ENGLAND';
```

Comment: . . This is what you get for storing data in columns that should actually be in rows.  Your `EN_TEXT` table should have a separate row for each heading -- that is, by rows rather than by columns.

Comment: Don't you have countrId (a FK) in the `EN_TEXT` table to connect to `Countrys` table ?

Comment: What is the expected output? All en_text values as rows?

Answer (score 2):

You could use conditional aggregation to pivot the tags

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    C.ID as CountryID,
    C.Type AS CountryType,
    MAX(CASE WHEN C.DESCRIPTION = T.TAG THEN T.Text END) AS CountryText,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_TITLE') THEN T.Text END) AS CountryTitle,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_1') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_2') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_3') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_4') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_5') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_6') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_7') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading7,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_8') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading8,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_9') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading9,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_10') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading10,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_11') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading11,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_12') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading12,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_13') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading13,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_14') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading14,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_15') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading15,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_16') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading16,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_17') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading17,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_18') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading18,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_19') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading19,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG = CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'_HEADING_20') THEN T.Text END) AS Heading20
FROM Countrys AS C
LEFT JOIN EN_TEXT AS T 
  ON T.TAG LIKE CONCAT(C.COUNTRYTAG,'%')
  -- AND (T.TAG LIKE '%TITLE' OR T.TAG LIKE '%HEADING%')
WHERE C.Type = 'Country_ENGLAND'
GROUP BY C.ID, C.Type;
```

Well, it's still a bit long winded.
But it only needs 1 join, so it should be faster.

And in the criteria used in the CASE's you could instead use a `LIKE`.
Because the `ON` clause already assures the COUNTRYTAG.

F.e.

```
... MAX(CASE WHEN T.TAG LIKE '%HEADING_1' THEN T.Text END) AS Heading1, ...
```

But then you'll have to take the calculated risk that in a `LIKE` an underscore `_` is a placeholder for any 1 character.

Comment: I would even bet that there is only a single record for the country via C.Type = 'Country_ENGLAND', so you would not even need the max() or group by.  I would ask the original post person, confirm and simplify.

Comment: Thanks LukStorms for your response. I will certainly try this and Salman's below.

Comment: @DRapp you are correct there is only one entry , however the country could be, for example Country_Germany etc I'm just trying to get the main query working before I start working with multiple countries.

Comment: @DRapp Yes, there's probably only on C.ID per Type. But the grouping is needed to PIVOT the tags.

Comment: You're right, my bad :)  eyes not quite working yet this morning :)